# unicode normalization algorithm in python

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to implement the Unicode normalization (NFC, NFD) in Python.

Yes, I am aware that I can use `unicodedata.normaliza()`. But, I want to just learn to do it.

So, I take the input as `é`. 
NFD should give the output as e + ́

My approach:

```
s = 'é'
s_len = len(s)
l = list()
for i in range(0, s_len):
    l.append(ord(s[i])
# Now l has two elements [195, 169]
```

Next, I did chr(195) which gave a string this - `'\xc3'`. Now when I try to print this, it gives me a mojibake character.

How should I proceed next?

Comment: Read the [relevant standard section](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/), and download the data tables. Unicode normalization mostly consists of a bunch of table lookups, and you're not going to get anywhere without the tables.

Comment: Which data tables?

Comment: I think just [UnicodeData.txt](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt).

Comment: Also, say which Python version you're on. It looks like you're on Python 2, and you're inadvertently working with a bytestring containing the UTF-8 encoding of your Unicode text instead of an actual Unicode string. You need to be working with Unicode strings.

Comment: "I can use unicodedata.normaliza(). But, I want to just learn to do it." This... is madness...

Answer (score 0):

As [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) noticed already in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43685143/unicode-normalization-algorithm-in-python#comment74416779_43685143):

> It looks like you're on Python 2, and you're inadvertently working
>   with a bytestring containing the UTF-8 encoding of your Unicode text
>   instead of an actual Unicode string. You need to be working with
>   Unicode strings.

Output from the following script might help you with deeper insight (note that `['0xc3', '0xa9']` is UTF-8 byte sequence for *Latin Small Letter E With Acute*):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import unicodedata

for s in 'é', r'é', u'é', unicodedata.normalize( 'NFD', u'é'):

    ### print ( '-')
    s_len = len( s)
    l = list()
    L = list()

    for i in range( 0, s_len):
        l.append(      ord( s[i]))
        L.append( hex( ord( s[i])))

    print ( s_len, '\t', s, '\t', repr( s), '\t', l, '\t' if s_len == 2 else '\t\t', L)
```

**Output** (note that above script is written to work in both `Python 2` and `Python 3` under *Windows OS*):

```
==> py -2 D:\test\Python\Py\43685143.py
2        é       '\xc3\xa9'      [195, 169]      ['0xc3', '0xa9']
2        é       '\xc3\xa9'      [195, 169]      ['0xc3', '0xa9']
1        é       u'\xe9'         [233]           ['0xe9']
2        é       u'e\u0301'      [101, 769]      ['0x65', '0x301']

==> py -3 D:\test\Python\Py\43685143.py
1        é       'é'     [233]           ['0xe9']
1        é       'é'     [233]           ['0xe9']
1        é       'é'     [233]           ['0xe9']
2        é       'é'     [101, 769]      ['0x65', '0x301']

==>
```

Also compare documentation:

- `Python 2` [Sequence Types — `str`, `unicode`, `list`, `tuple`, `bytearray`, `buffer`, `xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)
- `Python 3` [Text Sequence Type — `str`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str)